# Setting color for a particular value when using d3.scale.threshold()

Tags: d3.js

My code colors blue for values ranging from 50-150, colors Yellow for values grater than 150. I am trying add new colors to my color scale white for value that are exactly equal to zero. When I add a new color to the range say [WHITE, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW]. It eliminates yellow and maps only the first three colors in the range. With the threshold scale can we even set colors for values that are exactly equal to zero?

Right now I have my scale set up in my code like this :

```
var scale = d3.scale.threshold().domain([50,150]).range([GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW]);
```

I have tried couple of fiddle examples specified on stack overflow those examples work but they don't work for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a specific color value with an `if` inside the "fill" atribute, but you can do that with the threshold scale as well. Your problem here is just the domain. According to the API:

> If the number of values in the scale's range is N + 1, the number of values in the scale's domain must be N.

So, you have to define your color scale like this:

```
var scale = d3.scale.threshold()
    .range(["white", "green", "blue", "yellow"])
    .domain([0.001, 100, 150]);
```

With the scale above, any value below 0.001 will be associated to "white", between 0.001 and 100 to green, between 100 and 150 to blue and above 150 to yellow.

If you need to set white only to values *exactly* equal to zero, create an if:

```
.attr("fill", function(d){
    if(d === 0){
        return "white"
    } else {
        //your "else" condition    
    }
});
```

Check this snippet (look at the values inside `data` and the colors of the circles):

```js
var colors = d3.scale.threshold()
.range(["white", "green", "blue", "yellow"])
.domain([0.001, 100, 150]);

var data = [0, 140, 100, 170, 120, 0, 120, 10];

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", 500)
 .attr("height", 200);
 
var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 
circles.attr("r", 20)
 .attr("cy", 50)
 .attr("cx", function (d, i){ return 30 + i*60})
 .attr("stroke", "gray")
 .attr("fill", function(d){ return colors(d)});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```