# D3JS: set colour gradient above a certain threshold

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying out this [D3 heatmap example](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/heatmap_style.html). I'd like to implement slightly more complex colouring logic - all values below 30 will simply have a red `fill`, and above 30 to follow the `Blues` colour gradient.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793897/setting-color-for-a-particular-value-when-using-d3-scale-threshold), but this applies constant colours to different parts of a domain (e.g. red for values 0 to 50, blue for 50 to 100...) rather than flipping from a constant colour to a colour gradient. I could follow that answer and manually implement a domain of a single red and a sufficiently large set of blues from raw HTML colour codes, but I'd like a more elegant solution that implements the scale of blues for me, particularly because I won't know what the maximum value of possible range inputs will be.

I tried to modify the `attr("fill")` line to the following, but it won't work - it applies the red correctly, but the non-red squares just appear black, which tells me that the colour gradient isn't kicking in for some reason:

```
...
// Build color scale
var myColor = d3
    .scaleSequential()
    .interpolator(d3.interpolate)
    .domain([30, 100]); //Doesn't matter if I set the domain to [0.001, 100] or [30, 100]
...
.style("fill", function (d) { 
    if (d.value < 30) {
        return "red"
    } else {
        return myColor(d.value);
    };
})
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a function to interpolate between colors. You've specified d3.interpolate, but you haven't given it any values to interpolate between, eg:

```
  d3.interpolate("steelblue","yellow")
```

```js
// Build color scale
var myColor = d3
    .scaleSequential()
    .interpolator(d3.interpolate("steelblue","yellow"))
    .domain([30, 100]); 

var data = d3.range(100)



d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", 300)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("x", (d,i) => i%10 * 22)
  .attr("y", (d,i) => Math.floor(i/10) * 22)
  .style("fill", function (d) { 
    if (d < 30) {
        return "red"
    } else {
        return myColor(d);
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Or passed it a [pre-built](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic) interpolator for different color schemes, eg:

```
 d3.interpolateBlues
```

```js
// Build color scale
var myColor = d3
    .scaleSequential()
    .interpolator(d3.interpolateBlues)
    .domain([30, 100]); 

var data = d3.range(100)



d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", 300)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("x", (d,i) => i%10 * 22)
  .attr("y", (d,i) => Math.floor(i/10) * 22)
  .style("fill", function (d) { 
    if (d < 30) {
        return "red"
    } else {
        return myColor(d);
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

*You can use d3.scaleSequential(interpoloator) instead of specifying the interpolator using the .interpoloator method:*

```js
// Build color scale
var myColor = d3
    .scaleSequential(d3.interpolateBlues)
    .domain([30, 100]); 

var data = d3.range(100)


d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", 300)
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("x", (d,i) => i%10 * 22)
  .attr("y", (d,i) => Math.floor(i/10) * 22)
  .style("fill", function (d) { 
    if (d < 30) {
        return "red"
    } else {
        return myColor(d);
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```